# Converting a number entered by a user to its fractional equivalent in c

Tags: c

I am new to programming.  My question is, how to convert a number entered by the user to its equivalent fraction?  So lets say the user is asked to enter two numbers for the cost of something.  How would I convert the cent part to the fraction?  Below is an example of what I have outputting to the screen and what would be entered by the user.  I am having an issue converting the 50 to 1/2 and so on for any other number that I need to convert to a fraction.  For this program, we are not allowed to use floats or doubles.

Output:

```
     ex)  What is the pound-cost of oranges?
          Dollar part: *4*
          Cent part: *50*
          The oranges are *4 + 1/2* dollars per pound.
```

Code:

```
int x;
int H;
printf("What is the pound-cost of oranges?\n");
printf("Dollar part first: ");
scanf("%d", &x);
printf("Cent part next: ");
scanf("%d", &B);
//B= sqrt(B/100);
B= B/100;
printf("...so oranges are %d + %d dollars per pound\n", x, B);  
//This part right here should be displaying 4 + 1/2 or whatever number the user enters.
```

The issue I am having is, I'm not sure how to convert the cent part such as 50 to a fraction (1/2) in fixed point without using doubles and floats.

Comment: The problem title says "fixed point", but the program seems to be using fractions for output.  Nothing in the problem mentions nor suggests fixed point.  Why did you bring up fixed point?  Because you appear to want reducing fractions, which are 100% unrelated to fixed point.

Comment: 50 cents is 50/100 dollars, you then find the GCD of each which is 50. Divide top and bottom by 50, which gives 1/2 dollar.

Answer (score 1):

Let c the cent part then the numerator of your fraction is `c/pgcd(c,100)` and the denominator is `100/(pgcd(100,c))`

Comment: From a mathematical point of view, this answer is correct.  But in practice, do you really want to print 4.6 as 4 + 3/5 and 4.12 as 4 + 3/25 and 4.02 as 4 + 1/50 ?

Comment: Either way could work, but we aren't allowed to use floats or doubles which is making this challenging.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see any float neither double in my answer (and in in @MooingDuck 's test)

Comment: @chqrlie this what was stated from the problem statement (as far as I understood)

Comment: @DARK_LUCK: If that's exactly the goal, you can use the `pgcd` approach, or simply iterate over the list of divisors of `100`, namely `{ 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100 }` and print the first fraction with no remainder.  You probably should first special case `0`.